# Breaking median records

Tags: stochastic-processes, order-statistics

$\newcommand{\median}{\operatorname{median}}$
Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are independent identically distributed real random variables.  The process $Y_n=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\},\quad n=1,2,3,\ldots$ has been studied; one may ask, for example, what is the expected waiting time until the next time, after $n$, that the maximum increases, i.e. the "record is broken".

Now do with medians what was done above with maximums:
\begin{align}
N_1 & = \min\{ n : X_n = \median\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} \} \qquad\text{(So $\Pr(N_1=1)=1.$)} \\[8pt]
N_2 & = \min\{n\ge N_1 : X_n = \median\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\} \\[8pt]
N_3 & = \min\{n\ge N_2 : X_n = \median\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\} \\[8pt]
N_4 & = \min\{n\ge N_3 : X_n = \median\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\} \\[8pt]
& {}\  \vdots
\end{align}

So the question is: What can be said about the probability distribution of the process $\{N_n : n = 1,2,3,\ldots\}$ or about $\{X_{N_n} : n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some preliminary observations:

The analysis seems slightly simpler if we'd consider only odd values of $n$ (i.e: double time steps), and continuos densities.

In this case, when we go from $2n-1$ to $2n+1$, the median keeps unchanged if the two new values fall on each side of the previous median, which has probability $2 F_x(a) (1-F_x(a))$ - where $a$ is the previous median value. Obviously, this tends to 1/2 when $n$ is large.

We can also compute the conditional probability that the median increases by an amount $\delta>0$ as:

$$f_{m(2n+1) \mid m(2n-1)}(a+\delta,a)=(1-F_x(a))(n+1)\left(\frac{1-F_X(a+\delta)}{1-F_X(a)}\right)^n f_X(a+\delta)$$

An analogous expression can be obtained for the probability of decrease, and hence it is possible, in principle, to compute the joint probability for the median value for odd $n$.

Update: Actually, the above is not enough to compute the full joint probabilities, because the sequence of medians is not a markov process - knowing the previous values gives less information than knowing all previous values.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically for a continuous distribution, the result seems to be that the probability that the median of $2n-1$ terms is a new record among the first $n$ medians of odd samples is $\frac1{2n-1}$.

As a simple example, the median of $3$ samples is strictly greater than the median of $1$ sample when $X_1 < X_2 < X_3$ or  $X_1 < X_3 < X_2$, two of the six equally likely permutations, so with probability $\frac13$.

Here is a simulation in R, run a hundred thousand times looking at the first ten medians of odd samples.  This simulation uses a uniform distribution but, since we are only looking at ranks, any continuous distribution will do.

```
set.seed <- 2023
numbermedians <- 10
cases <- 100000

recordmedian <- function(n){
  x <- runif(1)
  topsofar <- x
  record <- TRUE
  for (i in 2:n){
    x[(2*i-2):(2*i-1)] <- runif(2)
    m <- median(x)
    record[i] <- (m > topsofar)
    topsofar <- topsofar + record[i]*(m - topsofar)
    }
  return(record)
  }

sims <- replicate(cases, recordmedian(numbermedians ))  
probrecord <- rowMeans(sims)
names(probrecord) <-  2*(1:numbermedians)-1
probrecord
#      1       3       5       7       9      11      13      15      17      19 
#1.00000 0.33431 0.20024 0.14174 0.11103 0.08983 0.07568 0.06624 0.05777 0.05200
```

Plotting those probabilities against a simple hyperbola show how close the fit is.

```
plot(2*(1:numbermedians)-1, probrecord)
curve(1/x, from=1, to=2*numbermedians, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image: chart]